N series of integers, each of different size, get cartesian product
I have something like this:
{'event1': [2000, 3000, 4000], 'event2': [123, 456]}

but with N keys, not only two like the example
I need to get something like this:
[
{'event1': 2000, 'event2': 123},
{'event1': 2000, 'event2': 456},
{'event1': 3000, 'event2': 123},
{'event1': 3000, 'event2': 456},
{'event1': 4000, 'event2': 123},
{'event1': 4000, 'event2': 456}
]

As you see, the order does not matter and the size of the list is variable for each key.
How would you approach this problem?
I tried to decouple values from keys and iterate between the various lists but after that, I can't couple again the single values with their previous keys.

You can use itertools.product, but the data will need some massaging to make it generally applicable to multiple keys.
from itertools import product

data = {
    'event1': [2000, 3000, 4000],
    'event2': [123, 456],
    'event3': [771, 9]
}

# get the keys to ensure
keys = sorted(data)
[
    dict(zip(keys, tup)) 
    for tup in product(*[data[k] for k in keys])
]

This returns:
[{'event1': 2000, 'event2': 123, 'event3': 771},
 {'event1': 2000, 'event2': 123, 'event3': 9},
 {'event1': 2000, 'event2': 456, 'event3': 771},
 {'event1': 2000, 'event2': 456, 'event3': 9},
 {'event1': 3000, 'event2': 123, 'event3': 771},
 {'event1': 3000, 'event2': 123, 'event3': 9},
 {'event1': 3000, 'event2': 456, 'event3': 771},
 {'event1': 3000, 'event2': 456, 'event3': 9},
 {'event1': 4000, 'event2': 123, 'event3': 771},
 {'event1': 4000, 'event2': 123, 'event3': 9},
 {'event1': 4000, 'event2': 456, 'event3': 771},
 {'event1': 4000, 'event2': 456, 'event3': 9}]


import itertools

original_dict = {'event1': [2000, 3000, 4000], 'event2': [123, 456],  'event3': [0, 1]}

keys = original_dict.keys()
values = original_dict.values()

combinations = list(itertools.product(*values))

result = [dict(zip(keys, combination)) for combination in combinations]

{'event1': 2000, 'event2': 123, 'event3': 0}
{'event1': 2000, 'event2': 123, 'event3': 1}
{'event1': 2000, 'event2': 456, 'event3': 0}
{'event1': 2000, 'event2': 456, 'event3': 1}
{'event1': 3000, 'event2': 123, 'event3': 0}
{'event1': 3000, 'event2': 123, 'event3': 1}
{'event1': 3000, 'event2': 456, 'event3': 0}
{'event1': 3000, 'event2': 456, 'event3': 1}
{'event1': 4000, 'event2': 123, 'event3': 0}
{'event1': 4000, 'event2': 123, 'event3': 1}
{'event1': 4000, 'event2': 456, 'event3': 0}
{'event1': 4000, 'event2': 456, 'event3': 1}

This should work for original_dict of any length

Same answer as mine, but yours is cleaner.

Does [dict(zip(keys, combination)) for combination in combinations]  works only because in latest Python dictionaries are ordered, right?

@Lomiz what do you mean? If they aren't ordered, what should be broken in your opinion in that case?

Sorry, stupid question, now I got how it worked!

This looks like a cartesian product
Easiest way to do this operation is by using itertools.product from the standard library:
import itertools as it

original_dict = {'event1': [2000, 3000, 4000], 'event2': [123, 456]}

keys = original_dict.keys()

result = []

for values in it.product(*(original_dict[key] for key in keys)):
   result.append({key: value for key, value in zip(keys, values)})

print(result)


output:
[{'event1': 2000, 'event2': 123},
 {'event1': 2000, 'event2': 456},
 {'event1': 3000, 'event2': 123},
 {'event1': 3000, 'event2': 456},
 {'event1': 4000, 'event2': 123},
 {'event1': 4000, 'event2': 456}]


oh true, I misread, I'll edit that

from itertools import product

original_dict = {'event1': [2000, 3000, 4000], 'event2': [123, 456]}


[dict(zip(original_dict.keys(), values)) for values in product(*original_dict.values()]

